# How to use m2 value in probability?

Tags: probability

An army tank $2$ $m$ wide needs to travel $20$ $m$ to cross minefield. The enemy that laid the minefield is known to have a standard practise of randomly placing $210$ mines per hectare ($10000$ $m^2$). The tank will set of any mine that it passes over. If the tank sets off any single mine then the armour protecting the engine will crack, but the engine will keep working. However, setting off a second mine will damage the engine and stop the tank in its tracks. What is the probability that the tank will make it to the other side of the minefield?

Assume that the tank makes it to the other side. What is probability that the armour protecting the engine will not have been cracked?

Assume that there is another mine field with the same density of mines that is wide enough that it is unlikely that a tank will be able to get to the other side without being stopped. A large number of tanks line up side by side and start crossing this minefield. what do you expect the median distance travelled by the tanks to be?

Note:Less tanks would be blown up if they followed each another, as the first tank would explode the mines and the following tanks would have a clear path. This is not happening in this question because the commander is worried that it is easier for the enemy to shoot tanks when they all follow the same line.

I'm guessing this would be poisson distribution. But with all the info from the question, I don't even know how to place my mean or x... :(
Can anyone please guide and explain me... Thanks

Comment: Please do not use the tag (poisson-geometry) for questions related to Poisson processes or Poisson random variables. These are unrelated.